# iMac screen doesn't turn on if no keyboard present

Tags: macos, display, imac, power-management

I have a spare 2007 iMac which I'm using to display photos in my house.  The iMac is set to boot & shutdown automatically at scheduled times, and display photos from my library using the screensaver.

Everything works well except that the iMac won't turn the display on at boot time without a keyboard connected.  I can force the display on by connecting remotely, after which it remains on (I had to use `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.RemoteManagement RestoreMachineState -bool NO` to stop the display turning back off after the Remote Desktop session disconnects).

How do I force the display to come on at boot or login time (don't mind which) without needing a keyboard connected?  I suspect something from `pmset` (e.g. `pmset displaysleep 0`) would do the trick but nothing so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to also remove the requirement for a password after the screensaver starts (disable screen lock).

Answer (score 2):

Running `caffeinate -u` after booting should do the trick.

This simulates a user activity which wakes up the display if it is asleep.

Comment: That wakes the display up & shows the lock screen, but after the timeout it turns off again.

Comment: Maybe that happens because of `pmset displaysleep 0`? You could specify the duration of the user activity with `caffeinate -ut 86400` where 86400 is the time in seconds but that wouldn't be a very "clean" solution.